# Is it possible to vectorize this numpy array comparison?

Tags: python, numpy, comparison, vectorization

I have these two numpy arrays in Python:

```
a = np.array(sorted(np.random.rand(6)*6)) # It is sorted.
b = np.array(np.random.rand(3)*6)
```

Say that the arrays are

```
a = array([0.27148588, 0.42828064, 2.48130785, 4.01811243, 4.79403723, 5.46398145])
b = array([0.06231266, 1.64276013, 5.22786201])
```

I want to produce an array containing the indices where `a` is `<=` than each element in `b`, i.e. I want exactly this:

```
np.argmin(np.array([a<b_i for b_i in b]),1)-1
```

which produces `array([-1,  1,  4])` meaning that `b[0]<a[0]`, `a[1]<b[1]<a[2]` and `a[4]<b[2]<a[5]`.

Is there any native numpy fast vectorized way of doing this avoiding the `for` loop?

Comment: You can use searchsorted: `np.searchsorted(a, b) - 1`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem promote your comment to answer. It does exactly what I want and is the fastest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your *specific* question, i.e., a vectorized way to get the equivalent of `np.array([a<b_i for b_i in b]`, you can take advantage of broadcasting, here, you could use:

```
a[None, ...] < b[..., None]
```

So:

```
>>> a[None, ...] < b[..., None]
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

Importantly, for broadcasting:

```
>>> a[None, ...].shape,  b[..., None].shape
((1, 6), (3, 1))
```

Here's the [link to the official numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) to understand broadcasting. Some relevant tidbits:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes
> element-wise. It starts with the trailing (i.e. rightmost) dimensions
> and works its way left. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1
>
> ...
>
> When either of the dimensions compared is one, the other is used. In
> other words, dimensions with size 1 are stretched or “copied” to match
> the other.

#### Edit

As noted in the comments under your question, using an entirely different approach is much better *algorithmically* than your own, brute force solution, namely, taking advantage of binary search, using `np.searchsorted`

Comment: The `searchsorted` solution of @hilberts_drinking_problem is much more efficient for big arrays. This solution runs is quadratic time while the other run in pseudo-linear time. Not to mentions the amount of RAM needed.

Comment: @JérômeRichard sure, but this answer only to address the specific question in the OP. Definitely, the entirely different approach here would be preferable to begin with.  But understanding broadcasting is an important `numpy` skill